# Change variable types in data frame

Tags: r

Is there an efficient way to change all variable types in a data frame?

I have many large data frames. Sometimes there is one more line at the bottom that does not include real data. If i automatically read in the data frames, the variable types are automatically set to type character (because of the last line which has random input mostly letters). 
If i then delete the last line.
How do i transform all variables that include only numbers to integer?
(Optimally just one line)

Here a short example of what i am looking for:

```
A <- c(rep(1,5),'X')
B <- c(1:6)
C <- rep('C',6)
D <- c(rep(10,5),'Y')

dat <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
dat <- dat[dat$A=='1',]

is.character(dat$A) #should be integer, as well as dat$D and optionally others
is.integer(dat$B)
is.character(dat$C)
```

Comment: See `?type.convert`. For 3.5+, just `type.convert(dat)` works. Otherwise try `dat[]<-lapply(dat,type.convert)`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. @akrun: great answer! df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))